# Select Multiple Options from a dropdown list and input selected options to input field

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I would like to be able to make multiple selection in a dropdown list and have those selected input written onto an input field with HTML, CSS and JS. I am using bootstrap and this is what I got so far, but haven't been able to find out how to select multiple items and have those selection being written into the input field. I tried `<select multiple>` but doesn't seems to work.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Nestia Umbrella</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./app.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/86fa3c1316.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="input-group">
        <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect04" aria-label="Example select with button addon" placeholder="Services Rendered">
            <option value="General Cleaning">General Cleaning</option>
            <option value="Change Battery">Change Battery</option>
            <option value="Re-align Spring">Re-align Spring</option>
            <option value="Replace Spring">Replace Spring</option>
            <option value="Replace Battery Cover Screw">Replace Battery Cover Screw</option>
        </select>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<select multiple>` works. You need select them with ctrl or shift key.

Comment: @zmag I am building this as a mobile first site, how do I select multiple on mobile?

Comment: @TengBankWei Just use `<select multiple>`. Mobile browsers will handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to write selections to a input, you will need a script.
Having bootstrap or not, will not affect this.

You could do something like this:

```
var select = document.getElementById("inputGroupSelect04");
var input = document.getElementById("input");

select.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
  const selected = document.querySelectorAll('#inputGroupSelect04 option:checked');
  const values = Array.from(selected).map(el => el.value);
  
  input.value = values.join(', ');
})
```

I have created an example here:  https://codepen.io/bj-rn-nyborg/pen/WNGNwpV

Answer (score 1):

Please find the multi-select drop-down sample code below. You can use the cdn below.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/bbbootstrap/libraries@main/choices.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/bbbootstrap/libraries@main/choices.min.js"></script>
```

if you are using react you can use with **npm**

```
npm install choices.js
```

with **yarn**

```
yarn add choices.js
```

You can initialize this drop-down using the javascript.

Refer this https://github.com/Choices-js/Choices#readme document to use options for drop-down menu.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    
     var multipleSelectDropdown = new Choices('#inputGroupSelect04', {
        removeItemButton: true
      }); 
     
     
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/bbbootstrap/libraries@main/choices.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/bbbootstrap/libraries@main/choices.min.js"></script>

<div>
<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
<label class="col-3">Select the something</label>
<select id="inputGroupSelect04" placeholder="Services Rendered" multiple>
        <option value="General Cleaning">General Cleaning</option>
        <option value="Change Battery">Change Battery</option>
        <option value="Re-align Spring">Re-align Spring</option>
        <option value="Replace Spring">Replace Spring</option>
        <option value="Replace Battery Cover Screw">Replace Battery Cover Screw</option>
    </select>
</div>
</div>
```